# C# - How do I store a string to file (StreamWriter) if it's over a certain number of letters?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read text from a file and then if the number of letters is over 5 it needs to store the words over 5 in a separate file.

New to this and need help please :)

Comment: do you mean 5 letters like `abcde`? then just write `if(str.Length > 5)  write();`

Comment: What I have so far is foreach (string s in path)
                {
                    if (s.Length > 5)
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }

Comment: But it says cannot convert char to string, but the .text file it reads from is set as a string so i'm confused.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). you should include part of the code that has issue in your question so others can see what is happening so they may be able to help.

Comment: Okay, sorry it's my first question. thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want reach this, but maybe it will help you:

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText("textpath.txt");
 File.WriteAllText("newFilePath.txt", text.Substring(5).ToString());
```

String "text" is reading specified file and then it is written to another file without first 5 chars.
Here is secured (for exceptions) program fragment:

```
if (File.Exists("textpath.txt"))
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText("textpath.txt");
            if (text.Length < 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File does not contains 5 characters");
            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllText("newFilePath.txt", text.Substring(5).ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Complete");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File not exist");
        }
```

Comment: This will not work. if text is less than `6` length then substring will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below is the answer :

```
//get text of the file
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
string over_text = "";
string five_first_letters = "";
//check if letters are more than 5
if(text.Lenght > 5){
//get the five first letters of file text
 five_first_letters = text.Substring(0,5);
//set the new string that does not contain the first five letters
 over_text = text.Replace(five_first_letters,"");
//write the new file
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText("new_file.txt",over_text);
}
```